# Comparação de dados em Arquivos [C]

Tags: c, arquivo, comparação

Eu desejo fazer um algoritmo que pegue um nome em um arquivo X e veja se este nome existe em outro arquivo Y, caso não exista ele escreve esse nome em um terceiro arquivo Z. (Basicamente um algoritmo que aponta os faltantes em uma lista de presença).
Tentei fazer isso no algoritmo abaixo mas não funcionou, alguém poderia apontar erros na estrutura lógica cujo o impedem de funcionar?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct tipo_nome{
    char nomePessoa[50];
} nome;

void main(){
    int i, k=0;
    nome nome1, nome2;
    FILE *file1, *file2, *file3;
    file1 = fopen("listaCompleta.txt", "r");
    file2 = fopen("listaPresenca.txt", "r");
    file3 = fopen("listaFaltantes.txt", "a+");

    do{
        fread(&nome1, sizeof(nome), 1, file1);
        do{
            fread(&nome2, sizeof(nome), 1, file2);
            if(strcmp(nome1.nomePessoa, nome2.nomePessoa)==0){
                k=1;
            }
        }while(!feof(file2) && k==0);

        if(k==0){
            fwrite(&nome1, sizeof(nome), 1, file3);
        }
        k=0;    
    }while(!feof(file1));

}
```

Comment: Precisa mesmo ser em [tag:C]? Um shell script resolveria sua vida muito mais facilmente

Comment: Sim, infelizmente tem de ser em C

Comment: Consigo escrever aqui um algoritmo com eficiência muito baixa, mas que atende perfeitamente seu caso. Para otimizar, já estou colocando alternativas na resposta como ordenar os conjuntos de dados ou usar uma estrutura de busca eficiente, como um hash ou árvore, mas não me delongo demais no assunto pois o seu foco aqui não é velocidade.

Comment: Você também pediu um algoritmo, então estou tomando a liberdade de por a ideia, sem muito foco no C propriamente dito

Answer (score 1):

Você deseja criar o seguinte conjunto `C`:

[image: criação do conjunto desejado]

Para tal, precisa responder a duas perguntas:

1. Como identificar `e` pertencente a `A`?
2. Como identificar `e` não pertencente a `B`?

Como no nosso caso `A` é um arquivo, então `e` pertence a `A` caso ele seja o resultado da leitura do arquivo. Então com isso conseguimos responder à primeira pergunta.

Agora, como saber se `e` não pertence a `B`? A operação de não pertinência implica no seguinte:

[image: e não pertence a B, então nenhum elemento b é e]

Se `B` for um conjunto comum, isso significa que vou precisar sempre comparar com todos os seus elementos para me certificar de que realmente `e` não pertence a `B`. Mas não precisamos nos ater a conjuntos comuns, posso ter conjuntos ordenados, mapas de hash ou árvore com os nomes, todas essas alternativas permitem que sejam feitas otimizações na quantidade de comparações feitas. Uma estrutura de dados de busca eficiente reduzirá o número de operações realizadas.

Para o escopo desta resposta, não estou otimizando a quantidade de comparações. Também estou levando em conta que o arquivo que contém o conjunto `B` seja relativamente pequeno, com alguns megabytes no máximo.

Como o conjunto `B` é sempre consultado como um todo, e o conjunto `A` só tem de importância a geração do próximo elemento, na inicialização do meu algoritmo vou pré-carregar totalmente `B`. A inicialização do conjunto `A`, neste caso, vai ser simplesmente abrir o arquivo.

A ideia geral é mais ou menos a seguinte:

```
inicializa conjunto A
inicializa conjunto B
faça:
    pegue _e_ o próximo elemento de A
    se _e_ não pertence a B:
        adiciona _e_ em C
enquanto não chegou ao fim do conjunto A
```

A inicialização de `A` seria somente a abertura do arquivo. Se fôssemos tentar otimizar as comparações entre `A` e `B`, poderíamos usar alguma estrutura de dados em `A` como um vetor ordenado.

```
inicialização conjunto A:
    abre arquivo "listaCompleta"
```

A inicialização do conjunto `B` aqui é sua leitura completa. Como não sabemos sua dimensão total a priori, podemos usar uma lista encadeada, cujo nó contém uma estrutura `nome` e um ponteiro para o próximo elemento da lista ligada:

```
inicialização conjunto B:
    nodo_lista *conjuntoB = NULL
    abre arquivo "listaPresenca"
    faça:
        nodo_lista *novoElemento = malloc(sizeof(nodo_lista))
        novoElemento->next = conjuntoB
        lê do arquivo "listaPresenca" no endereço &(novoElemento->valor)
        se a leitura deu certo:
            conjuntoB = novoElemento
    enquanto não der fim do arquivo "listaPresenca"
    fecha arquivo "listaPresenca"
```

Pegar o próximo elemento é só dar um `fread` do jeito que você fez:

```
pegue _e_ o próximo elemento de A:
    nome _e_
    lê do arquivo "listaCompleta" no endereço &_e_
```

A pertinência de `e` em `B` está sendo tratada observando todo o conjunto `B`, então precisamos fazer uma iteração completa:

```
_e_ pertence a B?
    nodo_lista *elementoB = conjuntoB
    enquanto elementoB != NULL:
        se elementoB->valor é igual a _e_:
            retorna "_e_ pertence a B"
        elementoB = elementoB->next
    retorna "_e_ não pertence a B"
```

A comparação entre dois elementos do tipo `nome` é comparando o campo `nomePessoa` dos dois objetos usando `strcmp`:

```
_a_ é igual a _b_?
    retorna strcmp(_a_.nomePessoa, _b_.nomePessoa) == 0
```

Adicionar elemento `e` ao conjunto `C` pode ser colocar o elemento novo em uma lista ou então escrever direto no arquivo com `fwrite`. Se for usada a alternativa de se por em uma lista, depois de se completar a análise de todos os itens de `A`, é necessário escrever esses itens no arquivo.

### Diferenças entre as nossas abordagens

Basicamente, estou preenchendo o conjunto `B` na memória de trabalho, enquanto você tenta manter o uso de memória externa (como HD). O problema na sua abordagem é que, antes de analisar novamente um item do conjunto `A`, seria necessário reposicionar a leitura do arquivo que representa o conjunto `B` para o começo novamente. Um simples `fseek` logo depois da leitura do primeiro arquivo, forçando o segundo arquivo a voltar para o começo, faria as vezes de retornar para o começo da iteração do conjunto `B`.

Como sua alternativa implica em uma quantidade quadrática de leituras à memória externa, eu não achei que fosse uma solução prática. Assim, usando uma quantidade linear de leituras à memória externa, preencho logo todo o conjunto `B`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação Jefferson, consegui analisar o problema melhor depois dela e montar um algoritmo um pouco diferente que resolveu meu problema

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma possível solução para o seu problema:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define LINHA_MAX_TAM  (100)
#define NOME_MAX_TAM   (50)


typedef struct pessoa_s
{
    char nome[ NOME_MAX_TAM + 1 ];
} pessoa_t;


int carregar_pessoas( const char * arq, pessoa_t ** pp, int * qtd )
{
    FILE * pf = NULL;
    char linha[ LINHA_MAX_TAM + 1 ] = {0};
    pessoa_t * p = NULL;
    int n = 0;

    pf = fopen( arq, "r" );

    if(!pf)
        return -1;

    while( fgets( linha, LINHA_MAX_TAM, pf ) )
    {
        linha[ strcspn(linha, "\n") ] = 0;
        n++;
        p = realloc( p, n * sizeof(pessoa_t) );
        strncpy( p[n-1].nome, linha, NOME_MAX_TAM );
    }

    fclose(pf);

    *qtd = n;
    *pp = p;

    return 0;
}


int gravar_pessoas( const char * arq, pessoa_t * p, int qtd )
{
    FILE * pf = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    pf = fopen( arq, "w" );

    if(!pf)
        return -1;

    for( i = 0; i < qtd; i++ )
        fprintf( pf, "%s\n", p[i].nome );

    fclose( pf );

    return 0;
}


int processar_ausencias( pessoa_t * pc, int qtdc, pessoa_t * pp, int qtdp, pessoa_t ** pa, int * qtda )
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int presente = 0;
    pessoa_t * p = NULL;
    int n = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < qtdc; i++ )
    {
        presente = 0;

        for( j = 0; j < qtdp; j++ )
        {
            if( !strcmp( pc[i].nome, pp[j].nome ) )
            {
                presente = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!presente)
        {
            n++;
            p = realloc( p, n * sizeof(pessoa_t) );
            strncpy( p[n-1].nome, pc[i].nome, NOME_MAX_TAM );
        }
    }

    *pa = p;
    *qtda = n;

    return 0;
}


int main( void )
{
    pessoa_t * lst_completa = NULL;
    int qtd_completa = 0;

    pessoa_t * lst_presenca = NULL;
    int qtd_presenca = 0;

    pessoa_t * lst_ausencia = NULL;
    int qtd_ausencia = 0;

    carregar_pessoas( "listaCompleta.txt", &lst_completa, &qtd_completa );
    carregar_pessoas( "listaPresenca.txt", &lst_presenca, &qtd_presenca );

    processar_ausencias( lst_completa, qtd_completa, lst_presenca, qtd_presenca, &lst_ausencia, &qtd_ausencia );

    gravar_pessoas( "listaFaltantes.txt", lst_ausencia, qtd_ausencia );

    free(lst_ausencia);
    free(lst_completa);
    free(lst_presenca);

    return 0;
}
```

**listaCompleta.txt**

```
JOSE
JOAO
ANTONIO
FRANCISCO
LUIZ
CARLOS
PEDRO
PAULO
MANOEL
LUCAS
```

**listaPresenca.txt**

```
JOSE
JOAO
LUIZ
PEDRO
PAULO
MANOEL
LUCAS
```

**listaFaltantes.txt**

```
ANTONIO
FRANCISCO
CARLOS
```